# Trane VX99 furnace fan to run

Tags: thermostat, furnace, blower

I would like to have the fan turn on and blow non-a/c.  I only see 2 wires coming from the thermostat.  In[image]

Comment: How about providing the tech info on your thermostat?

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple setup with R (24V power) and W1 (HEAT).  The fan is turned on automatically, along with HEAT, when the thermostat applies the power from R to the W1 connection.

The FAN terminal is labelled G and you need to connect that to the G terminal on your thermostat.  Then, provided you have a FAN ONLY setting on your thermostat, it can control the fan independently.

You're going to have to run a "G" wire though since the currently line appears to only have 2 wires.

Comment: I agree lots of times I add a simple toggle switch on the furnace for this application.   Between R/G terminals switch on turns on the fan if in a closet or attached garage it works fine even doorbell wire is enough for this or some automotive wiring like for trailer lights will be fine. +

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  Just the answer I was looking for.  I think I will just run a jumper between the R/G terminals.  Strangely this furnace is in a green house I am using.

Comment: I jumped the R/G terminals and the fan came on but it is going at low speed.  Any way to make it run at full speed?

Comment: You'll need to refer to the unit's manual.  There doesn't appear to be a fan control on the board that you shared a photo of.  It's possible that in fan only mode, the unit runs the fan at a lower speed.